# Can't update visibility of element from code-behind via binding (WP8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="RegionList" Loaded="RegionList_Loaded" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,0,0,10" SelectionChanged="RegionList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <selectors:RegionDataTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                        <selectors:RegionDataTemplateSelector.ItemTemplateFirstLayer>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayedName}" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityOption, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="24" Margin="5,5,5,5"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </selectors:RegionDataTemplateSelector.ItemTemplateFirstLayer>
                        <selectors:RegionDataTemplateSelector.ItemTemplateSecondLayer>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayedName}" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityOption, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="25,5,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="350" FontSize="24"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </selectors:RegionDataTemplateSelector.ItemTemplateSecondLayer>
                        <selectors:RegionDataTemplateSelector.ItemTemplateThirdLayer>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayedName}" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityOption, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="45,5,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="350" FontSize="24"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </selectors:RegionDataTemplateSelector.ItemTemplateThirdLayer>
                    </selectors:RegionDataTemplateSelector>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

C#:

```
private void FilterBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var allRegions = (RegionList.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<RegionTree>);
        foreach (var region in allRegions)
        {
            if (region.DisplayedName.IndexOf(RegionFilter.Text) >= 0)
            {
                region.VisibilityOption = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                region.VisibilityOption = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
        RegionList.ItemsSource = allRegions;
    }
```

When my list loads first time, all items have VisibilityOption = Visibility.Visible. When I press the button some of them have from that moment VisibilityOption = Visibility.Collapsed. But I still can see them in UI. What is going wrong?

**EDIT:**

RegionTree:

```
public class RegionTree : BindableBase
{
    public bool IsFirstLayer { get; set; }
    public bool IsSecondLayer { get; set; }
    public bool IsThirdLayer { get; set; }
    public Visibility VisibilityOption { get; set; }
    public string Name;
    public string Code;
    public string RUName;
    public string SWNE;
    public string DisplayedName
    {
        get
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString() == "ru-RU" && RUName != null)
            {
                return RUName;
            }
            else { return Name; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have VisibilityOption Property?

Comment: @vits, in RegionTree Class? Of course. More than it, if I set it as collapsed by default, nothing will appear in UI. The problem that, if I update this property, UI doesn't change at all.

Comment: could you add your code of property?

Comment: @vits, added the whole class structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to raise a PropertyChanged Event when the property is changed, otherwise your Binding will not update. Your `BindingBase` Class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which you can/should use for notifications for the view

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged)

your Property should look like something like this:

```
public Visibility VisibilityOption
{
  get { return _visibilityOption; }
  set
  {
    if (_visibilityOption != value)
    {
      _visibilityOption = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityOption");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Visibility VisibilityOption { get; set; }
```

This is not proper way to add property, you must use `OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityOption")` in order to update UI in `set`.just modify that property.you will be done.